# Inserting unrelated data while a transaction is occuring

Tags: mysql, transaction

I'm thinking about implementing transactions to my app to help with consistency issues. I'm using MySQL.

I'm wondering what might happen if while inserting several rows as a transaction, the server will also need to insert a single row, that is completely unrelated.

To be more clear, I will present a scenario (hypothetical) of a store:

The application server in running nodejs, and connected to a MySQL server. It then receives a request to add a stock of 50 new computers, and needs to insert the 50 rows representing their SN to a table `stock`, plus a row in another table `shipments`, all 51 rows must be inserted in an atomic manner (all or none). While this is happening, the same nodejs server receives a request to register a new customer, and is required to add one row to a table `customers`.

In that scenario, what will happen if the transaction fails and must be rolled-back? Will the row in `customers` be ommited as well? Is this scenario even possible? Or maybe it depends on the implementation, and if so, how to implement it so that this scenario is garanteed never to happen?

Comment: Transaction is "opened" on some connection/session, so you just need to use a separate connection for each request, then they will be independent. You can open new connection per request or use some pool, but that's a question for nodejs/stackoverflow and not here.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB for your database engine in MySQL? What version are you using?

Comment: I can use either one, this is more of a theoretical question.

Comment: MyISAM does not support transactions (ACID) at all, only table locks.

Comment: As I said, it's more of a theoretical question. Your comment from before pretty much provided the answer I wanted. If you would like to ellaborate and include it as an answer I will accept it. If you don't I would do it myself at a later time

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle *all* the writes in a single connection, then Plan A.  Note:  Moving from one "page" to another in a browser necessarily leads to another connection, hence Plan B.

Plan A:  `BEGIN; write...; COMMIT;`  And check for errors.  `ROLLBACK` on errors and retry the entire transaction.  If not successful, tell the user that his seat on the plane was taken and he must start over.

Plan B:  You must set up another table to keep track of "transactions" and be ready to rollback (etc) things *outside* of what InnoDB (much less MyISAM) can do for you.

Note:  If Plan A takes more than a few seconds, you are asking for trouble and for failures.  If it takes longer, switch to Plan B.

Answer (score 0):

A transaction binds together all the statements executed within that transaction.
Either *all* of them "happen" or *none* of them do.  The principle is called Atomicity.

> While this is happening, the same nodejs server receives a request to register a new customer, and is required to add one row to a table customers.

Transactions are started within the current connection/session.
Typically, a node.js server will open a *new* database connection to service this *new* request.  In that case, that connection can start its *own* transaction.

The first transaction, inserting 51 rows, will happen or not happen.
The second transaction, inserting a new customer, will happen or not happen.

The only time you really need to worry is when both transactions are trying to work with [the same row(s) in] the same table(s).  At that point (in MySQL anyway) one Transaction will *wait* for the other to complete.

> how to implement it so that this scenario is garanteed never to happen?

It **will** happen - many, *many* times, every single day.
Databases are specifically *built* to cope with it.